# Find all valid words when given a string of characters (Recursion / Binary Search)

Tags: java, recursion, binary-search

I'd like some feedback on a method I tried to implement that isn't working 100%. I'm making an Android app for practice where the user is given 20 random letters. The user then uses these letters to make a word of whatever size. It then checks a dictionary to see if it is a valid English word. 
The part that's giving me trouble is with showing a "hint". If the user is stuck, I want to display the possible words that can be made. I initially thought recursion. However, with 20 letters this can take quite a long time to execute. So, I also implemented a binary search to check if the current recursion path is a a prefix to anything in the dictionary. I do get valid hints to be output however it's not returning all possible words. Do I have a mistake here in my recursion thinking? Also, is there a recommended, faster algorithm? I've seen a method in which you check each word in a dictionary and see if the characters can make each word. However, I'd like to know how effective my method is vs. that one.

```
private static void getAllWords(String letterPool, String currWord) {
    //Add to possibleWords when valid word
    if (letterPool.equals("")) {
        //System.out.println("");
    } else if(currWord.equals("")){
        for (int i = 0; i < letterPool.length(); i++) {
            String curr = letterPool.substring(i, i+1);
            String newLetterPool = (letterPool.substring(0, i) + letterPool.substring(i+1));
            if(dict.contains(curr)){
                possibleWords.add(curr);
            }

            boolean prefixInDic = binarySearch(curr);
            if( !prefixInDic ){
                break;
            } else {
                getAllWords(newLetterPool, curr);
            }
        }
    } else {
        //Every time we add a letter to currWord, delete from letterPool
        //Attach new letter to curr and then check if in dict
        for(int i=0; i<letterPool.length(); i++){
            String curr = currWord + letterPool.substring(i, i+1);
            String newLetterPool = (letterPool.substring(0, i) + letterPool.substring(i+1));
            if(dict.contains(curr)) {
                possibleWords.add(curr);
            }
            boolean prefixInDic = binarySearch(curr);
            if( !prefixInDic ){
                break;
            } else {
                getAllWords(newLetterPool, curr);
            }
        }
    }

private static boolean binarySearch(String word){
    int max = dict.size() - 1;
    int min = 0;
    int currIndex = 0;
    boolean result = false;
    while(min <= max) {
        currIndex = (min + max) / 2;
        if (dict.get(currIndex).startsWith(word)) {
            result = true;
            break;
        } else if (dict.get(currIndex).compareTo(word) < 0) {
            min = currIndex + 1;
        } else if(dict.get(currIndex).compareTo(word) > 0){
            max = currIndex - 1;
        } else {
            result = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: You haven't given a really good explanation of what you are trying to do. I suggest updating your question with a concrete example. For example, the user is shown letters "f e h s r a" and they choose letters ... etc. " Walk thorough and explain an entire an example end-to-end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to speed up your algorithm is probably to use a [Trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) (a prefix tree)

Trie data structures offer two relevant methods. isWord(String) and isPrefix(String), both of which take O(n) comparisons to determine whether a word or prefix exist in a dictionary (where n is the number of letters in the argument). This is really fast because it doesn't matter how large your dictionary is.

For comparison, your method for checking if a prefix exists in your dictionary using binary search is O(n*log(m)) where n is the number of letters in the string and m is the number of words in the dictionary.

I coded up a similar algorithm to yours using a Trie and compared it to the code you posted (with minor modifications) in a very informal benchmark.
With 20-char input, the Trie took 9ms. The original code didn't complete in reasonable time so I had to kill it.

Edit:
As to why your code doesn't return all hints, you don't want to break if the prefix is not in your dict. You should continue to check the next prefix instead.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a recommended, faster algorithm?

See Wikipedia article on "[String searching algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm)", in particular the section named "[Algorithms using a finite set of patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm#Algorithms_using_a_finite_set_of_patterns)", where "finite set of patterns" is your dictionary.

The [Aho–Corasick algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_algorithm) listed first might be a good choice.